# Gitlab Pipeline Fails-Error: We don't support cucumber version 6

Tags: selenium, gitlab, protractor, cucumber, gitlab-ci

hi i have an angularJs project. We prepared E2E tests for the project. I want to integrate these tests into gitlab pipeline. The log I got from Pipeline is as follows;

```
npm run test
> protractor-typescript-cucumber@4.0.0 test
> protractor typeScript/config/config.js
[07:45:54] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[07:45:54] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[07:45:55] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://10.235.216.81:51027/wd/hub
[07:45:58] E/launcher - Error: Error: We don't support cucumber version 6
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/i3uGB66D/0/cloudnesiltech/delivery/bdd/bdd-delivery-web/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/lib/resultsCapturer.js:31:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Function.loadCustomFormatter (/builds/i3uGB66D/0/cloudnesiltech/delivery/bdd/bdd-delivery-web/node_modules/cucumber/lib/formatter/builder.js:110:29)
    at Function.getConstructorByType (/builds/i3uGB66D/0/cloudnesiltech/delivery/bdd/bdd-delivery-web/node_modules/cucumber/lib/formatter/builder.js:77:33)
    at Function.build (/builds/i3uGB66D/0/cloudnesiltech/delivery/bdd/bdd-delivery-web/node_modules/cucumber/lib/formatter/builder.js:38:40)
    at /builds/i3uGB66D/0/cloudnesiltech/delivery/bdd/bdd-delivery-web/node_modules/cucumber/lib/cli/index.js:104:31
[07:45:58] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

My package.json file;

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/cucumber": "^4.0.4",
    "@types/node": "^10.7.1",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.10",
    "all-contributors-cli": "^5.4.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^4.0.3",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^6.1.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript",
  "dependencies": {
    "cucumber": "^6.0.5",
    "webdriver-manager": "12.1.8"
  }
```

Comment: the error is self explanatory, no? upgrade your cucumber to v7

Comment: I run tests on my local  without any errors. Why does the pipeline give such an error?

Comment: because local version of cucumber is v7 I guess

Comment: I do not have cucumber installed on my local. I use npm install, then I start test

Comment: this not logical. You run tests that use cucumber, so it has to be installed, correct? when you run npm install it installs all packages from `package.json` that's where it's coming from